# How can i call a function using a variable?

Tags: c++

I was learning Heap data structure and as there are two types of Heaps, I wanted to provide an option to user to choose. I am making a normal program which provide option such as insert, traversal, search.

Now for insertion in both heaps I have made two functions i.e. min_insert() and max_insert().

```
class MinHeap{
Node *root;
int choice;
void min_insert();
void max_insert();
public:
    Heap(){
        root  = NULL;
        cout << "Do you want\n1.Max Heap\n2.Min Heap";
        }
};
```

I want to assign my function to a variable so that I do not have to write two set of code, one for case 1 and one for case 2.

Explanation:
How I was going to write code:

```
   Heap(){
    root  = NULL;
    cout << "Do you want\n1.Max Heap\n2.Min Heap";
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 1){
        cout << "1.INSERT\2.SEARCH\n3.TRAVERSAL";
        cin >> innerChoice;
        switch(innerChoice){
            case1: max_insert() ;break;
            case2: search();break;
            case3:traversal();break;
        }

    }
    else{
        cout << "1.INSERT\2.SEARCH\n3.TRAVERSAL";
        cin >> innerChoice;
        switch(innerChoice){
            case1: min_insert() ;break;
            case2: search();break;
            case3:traversal();break;
        }

    }

}
```

what I want to do:

```
Heap(){
        root  = NULL;
        cout << "Do you want\n1.Max Heap\n2.Min Heap";
        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 1){
        function_variable = max_insert();       
        }else{
            function_variable = min_insert();
        }
            cout << "1.INSERT\2.SEARCH\n3.TRAVERSAL";
            cin >> choice;
            switch(choice){
                case1: function_variable ;break;
                case2: search();break;
                case3:traversal();break;
            }

    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the best way to go about it, but so you at least know how to do what you are asking, read up on [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). If you are talking about 2 different classes implementing the same interface, you may want to use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to member function to provide the required indirection.

```
void (MinHeap::* pFunc)() = &MinHeap::max_insert;

MinHeap obj;
(obj.*pFunc)();
```

or, inside your class

```
(this->*pFunc)();
```

A pointer to member is a sort of selector, that when applied to an object of the class type results in a reference to that member of the class. For member functions, those can be then invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointer is the correct way :). I go with array of function pointers ..